# Mac Sounds are greyed off when headphones plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a problem with my mac.

When i am using internal speakers everything works fine however as soon as i insert headphones , the sounds icon is greyed out and there is no sounds to hear. Happening to all kind of headphones.

The preferences say " Digital out : The selected device has no output controls."

Comment: Does this always happen? And can you wiggle the headphone-jack around in the slot and see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a digital out device, the Mac simply passes the digital signal to the receiving device where the settings should be adjusted, this is the correct behavior. Unless your Mac is mistaking the headphones as a digital device when they are really analog, then this isn't a Mac issue. To determine if it is a Mac issue I'd try plugging in another analog audio source (different pair of headphones) to see if the problem is repeatable, otherwise it could be something with the headphones (or even the headphone cable).

Comment: I have tried multiple headphones, all give th same result. Maybe the jack is our of order?

Comment: Yep... it sounds like the computer is mistakenly identifying an analog cable as a digital one. could be something simple like some dirt or something trapped in the output jack or something that will require a visit to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System Preferences > Sound Settings > Output` and select your headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences > Sound Settings > Output and select your headphones.

This worked out well for me! Thanks a bunch

Comment: This is a thank you comment for [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140244/145449). Instead of posting a new answer, please gain reputation and upvote the answer that you found helpful.